# Adding hover option to seaborn heat maps

Tags: seaborn

I have 3 heat maps on the same plot in seaborn, of the same color. I know heatmaps should have different color, but is it possible to add a hover option, such that when I hover over a heat map, the details of the heat map pop up as a label so the heat maps can be distinguished?

I have the following code for the 3 heat maps, plotted in the same graph.

```
ax = sns.kdeplot(a.width, a.length, cmap="Blues", shade=True, shade_lowest=False,alpha=0.4)
ax = sns.kdeplot(b.width, b.length, cmap="Blues", shade=True, shade_lowest=False,alpha=0.4)
ax = sns.kdeplot(c.width, c.length, cmap="Blues", shade=True, shade_lowest=False, alpha 0.4)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You may look at the [event handling guide](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) on how to produce mouse events.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'll try it out